# Same image appearing for all elements

Tags: java, spring

I will go straight to the point.

Imagine I have collection like this:

`doc1`

```
title: doc1
state: state1
image: binary number...
```

`doc2`

```
title: doc2
state: state2
image: binary number...
```

Now, its standard to show in HTML `title` and `description` like this:

```
<tr th:each="randomSummerCamps:${randomSummerCamps}">
<div class="title">
    <h1>We think this trip best suit you.</h1>
    <h1 th:text="${randomSummerCamps.title}"></h1>
    <h1 th:text="${randomSummerCamps.state}"></h1>

   .....
```

Of course I have controller for that and that works fine, for each element is different title and state, its good. But problem is when I try to show picture for each element, and what is the problem? One image appear for all elements, instead of showing different images like title and state.

When I add this `<h1 th:text="${randomSummerCamps.image}"></h1>` program return me different value so for first document is:

```
title: Kieve Summer Camp
state: Nobleboro, USA
image: org.bson.types.Binary@96e8964c
```

and for second one is:

```
title: Raquette Lake Camp
state: New York, USA
image: org.bson.types.Binary@c8dcf05e
```

You see? Image return value is different, but when I add this to actaully show image:

```
<img th:if="${randomSummerCamps.image != null}" alt="sample" th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+randomImageSummerCamp}" src=""/>
```

Image is always same for all elements, both for doc1 and doc2.

I'm here for any other question.

Here is the github link so you can check whole code:

https://github.com/jankovicdev/TripAdvisorApp

Comment: [mcve] please (here, not anywhere external)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've always posted part of the codes that are needed here, the question always seems too crowded and people often don't want to help, so I thought it would be better via github.

Comment: Shouldn't be it like 
```<img th:if="${randomSummerCamps.image != null}" alt="sample" th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+randomImageSummerCamp.image}" src=""/>```

Comment: @AnoopLL I tried that already, that return me this error: `Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "'data:image/png;base64,'+randomImageSummerCamp.image" (template: "randomSummerCamps" - line 20, col 14)
`

Comment: may bad it should be ```<img th:if="${randomSummerCamps.image != null}" alt="sample" th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+randomImageSummerCamps.image}" src=""/>```